# Issue with mapKit and annotations

Tags: xcode, annotations, mapkit, overlays

I have an app here which uses MapKit, and I draw some overlays and annotations to it.

They do show up, but I have to move the map first or zoom in / out a bit before they are drawn.

Is there any fix to it?

Comment: Sounds like addAnnotation and addOverlay are being called from a background thread.  They should be called on the main thread.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862914/loading-annotations-from-url-using-background-thread-pins-doesnt-show-before-m.

Answer (score 1):

Just call it for map zoom and fit annotations:-
[self zoomToFitMapAnnotations:self.mapView];

- (void)zoomToFitMapAnnotations:(MKMapView*)aMapView {
  if([aMapView.annotations count] == 0)
      return;

  CLLocationCoordinate2D topLeftCoord;
  topLeftCoord.latitude = -90;
  topLeftCoord.longitude = 180;

  CLLocationCoordinate2D bottomRightCoord;
  bottomRightCoord.latitude = 90;
  bottomRightCoord.longitude = -180;

  for(PlaceMark *annotation in aMapView.annotations) {
      topLeftCoord.longitude = fmin(topLeftCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
      topLeftCoord.latitude = fmax(topLeftCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);

  ```
  bottomRightCoord.longitude = fmax(bottomRightCoord.longitude, annotation.coordinate.longitude);
  bottomRightCoord.latitude = fmin(bottomRightCoord.latitude, annotation.coordinate.latitude);
  ```

  }

  MKCoordinateRegion region;
  region.center.latitude = topLeftCoord.latitude - (topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 0.5;
  region.center.longitude = topLeftCoord.longitude + (bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 0.5;
  region.span.latitudeDelta = fabs(topLeftCoord.latitude - bottomRightCoord.latitude) * 1.1; // Add a little extra space on the sides
  region.span.longitudeDelta = fabs(bottomRightCoord.longitude - topLeftCoord.longitude) * 1.1; // Add a little extra space on the sides

  region = [aMapView regionThatFits:region];
  [aMapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
  }